# DB not getting created automatically for device data storage for upcoming bucket interval on IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, raspberry-pi3, cloudant, watson-iot

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to the IBM® Watson™ IoT Platform and two IBM® Cloudant® NoSQL DB services setup for storing device data. The bucket interval for both the DBs is setup as day. For some reason a new DB is not getting created for the next bucket interval on both the Cloudant NoSQL DB services. I was looking for some insight as to why this might be happening.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?  It may have been a temporary problem.  Let us know if it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary problem with IoT platform cloudant database creation around the time you posted this question.  That issue has been fixed, please let us know if you still are experiencing the problem.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the problem anymore. Thanks!